# Bouncing ideas for how to manage length of arrays for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c

I have two structs that have an int for the length of the fibonacci number and fibonacci itself in an integer array. Problem is the adding function for the fibonacci numbers (hugeAdd) is dependent on the length intereger in the fibonacci struct. I can call 'malloc' and reverse all the memory needed for the array but, when trying increase the length variable automatically to tell the adding function (hugeAdd) to keep adding more integers I can't figure it out. Here a list of the things i tried.

1. Tieing fibonacci length to a for loop as its were hugeAdd is called.
2. Seeing if both my Fibonacci digits at position 'x' are greater then 5 and incrementing length then.(This one kinda works but, I cant figure out its implementation because I have to hard code what digit to check.)
3. Tried setting fibonacci length to the integer that says how many time to run the loop.(Works for a couple rounds of adding but, then i get a segment fault in my function for deleting the structs (hugeDestory)).

Any ideas?

Fibonacci.h(This is the header file that contains struct def and etc)

```
#ifndef __FIBONACCI_H
#define __FIBONACCI_H

typedef struct HugeInteger
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold the digits of a huge integer
int *digits;

// the number of digits in the huge integer (approx. equal to arraylength)
int length;
} HugeInteger;


// Functional Prototypes

HugeInteger *hugeAdd(HugeInteger *p, HugeInteger *q);

HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p);

HugeInteger *parseString(char *str);

HugeInteger *parseInt(unsigned int n);

unsigned int *toUnsignedInt(HugeInteger *p);

HugeInteger *fib(int n);

double difficultyRating(void);

double hoursSpent(void);


#endif
```

Testcase4.c Class(Contains main function and test case to test function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

// print a HugeInteger (followed by a newline character)
void hugePrint(HugeInteger *p)
{
int i;

if (p == NULL || p->digits == NULL)
{
    printf("(null pointer)\n");
    return;
}

for (i = p->length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d", p->digits[i]);
printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
int i;
HugeInteger *p;

for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    printf("F(%d) = ", i);
    hugePrint(p = fib(i));
    hugeDestroyer(p);
}

return 0;
}
```

Fibonacci.c Class(This class has all the functions to run testcase4.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Fibonacci.h"

HugeInteger *hugeAdd(HugeInteger *p, HugeInteger *q)
{
HugeInteger *hugerInt = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));

int overhead=1,i,j,results=0;
 int *resultArray = NULL;

if(p == NULL || q == NULL || hugerInt == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}


if(p->length > q->length)
{
  resultArray = calloc(((p->length)+ overhead), sizeof(int));
  hugerInt->length = p->length;
  hugerInt->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * (p->length + overhead));

  if(resultArray == NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for(int k=0; k < p->length; k++)
  {
    if(k >= q->length)
    {
        results=p->digits[k];   //check for not skipping smaller int
        resultArray[k] = results + resultArray[k];
    }
    else{
 results = p->digits[k] + q->digits[k];
  if(results > 9 )
  {
      if(p->digits[k+1] == 0)
      {
          hugerInt->digits[k+1] = 1;
      }

      resultArray[k+1] = resultArray[k+1] + 1;

      results = results - 10;
    printf("length of resultArray is %d\n",p->length+1);
  }


      resultArray[k] = results;


  }
  }
}
else
{
  resultArray = calloc(((p->length)+ overhead)+ 1, sizeof(int));
  hugerInt->length = q->length;
  hugerInt->digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * (q->length)+ overhead);

  if(resultArray == NULL)
  {
      return NULL;
  }
  for(i=0; i < q->length; i++)
  {
   // printf("q length %d", q->length);
    if(i >= p->length) // Check if second struct passed is smaller then first one passed
    {
        results=q->digits[i];   //check for not skipping smaller int
        resultArray[i] = results;
    }
    else{
 results = q->digits[i] + p->digits[i];
  if(results > 9 )
  {
      printf("I is in larger then 9 check %d", i);
      if(p->digits[i+1] == 0)
      {
          hugerInt->digits[i+1] = 1;
      }

      printf("i is %d\n",i);
      printf("Assigning 1 to %d in resultarray\n", i);
      resultArray[i+1] = 1; // if value is greater then 9 the 1 carries and gets added to the result.(This is the part i think is going wrong) 

      results = results - 10;

    printf("length of resultArray is %d\n",p->length+1);
      printf("results:$d\n", results);
  }


      resultArray[i] = results; // Throws added values into array


    }
  }
}

printf("\n=================\n");
for(i=0; i < hugerInt->length; i++)
{
   hugerInt->digits[i] = resultArray[i];
}

free(resultArray);
return hugerInt;
} 

HugeInteger *fib(int n)
{
HugeInteger *fibInt = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));

HugeInteger *fatherFib = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));
HugeInteger *grandfatherFib = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger));


int j=1,fatherLength=0,grandfatherLength=0,fibLength=0,result, overhead=1;
unsigned int father, grandFather, fib, tempFather, tempGrandfather, tempFib;

fatherFib->digits = calloc((n + overhead),sizeof(int) );
fibInt->digits = calloc((n+overhead),sizeof(int));

grandfatherFib->digits = calloc((n + overhead),sizeof(int) );

  fatherFib->length = 1;
 grandfatherFib->length = 1;
 fibInt->length = 1;

 if(n == 0)
 {
     fibInt->digits[0] = 0;
     return fibInt;
 }



for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{


 if(i >= 1)
 {

  if(fatherFib->digits[0] >= 5 && grandfatherFib->digits[0] >= 5)
  {
  fibInt->length = 2;

  }
  else if(fatherFib->digits[1] >= 5 && grandfatherFib->digits[1] >= 5)
  {
  fibInt->length = 3;

  }
 }

 if(i == 0)
 {
     fatherFib->digits[0]= 0;
     grandfatherFib->digits[0]=1;
 }



fibInt = hugeAdd(fatherFib,grandfatherFib);

 grandfatherFib = fatherFib;


  if(fibInt->length == 2)
{
    printf("tens value in father fib %d\n", fatherFib->digits[1]);
}
fatherFib = fibInt;


}
 free(grandfatherFib->digits);
 free(grandFatherFib);
 return fatherFib;

}

HugeInteger *hugeDestroyer(HugeInteger *p)
{
if(p == NULL)
{
    return; // Null check
}


 free(p->digits);

 free(p->length);
 free(p);

 return NULL;

}

int power(int base, int numTimes)
{
int result=1,i=0;

if(numTimes == 1)
{
    return base;
}

for(;i < numTimes; i++)
{
    result = result * base;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: You could consider using `malloc` to get memory for a digit string that is 1 longer than the larger of the two previous values you want to add, plus possible terminator. Then after adding, `realloc` to the actual length needed. Or not bother reallocating for such a small difference.

Comment: @Weather Vane thanks for the suggestion but, i figured it out. I was able to figure out how to check if two digits add to 10 and assign the correct length.

Comment: The sum will only be longer than the larger of the two, if a carry travels through, but you need a complete addition to determine that. For example (I know these are not in the Fibonacci series) `8888888 + 1111112` will generate a carry that is propagated from the sum of the two l.s. digits.